# Files not syncing from on-premises to azure storage using Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

Files are not getting synced to the file storage from Windows 2012 R2 Server. The root files are synced to file storage, but the files inside any folder and its chain folders are not synced.

The event log has the below error:

```
Management discovery failed.

Discovery URI: https://tm-kailani-sin.one.microsoft.com/discovery/storagesyncserviceuids/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4566-8c07-82d9fa6620e6/registeredServers/4AXXXXB-XXXX-XXXX-BD82-226XXXXX484/managementEndpoint?api-version=1.2
Error message: The GET Management Endpoint request failed.
ErrorCode: 80131500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there were lots of files with spaces and special characters. Especially there were "." in the folder name and it was confusing the file copy for a good obvious reason. There were also multiple "." in a file name eg: "2016.12.hardware.txt". So I ran a PowerShell to replace the "." with empty space, it got sync in a couple of days. Suddenly one day everything was synced.